# How to make SingleChoiceAction_execute Synchronous?

Tags: c#, download, devexpress, execute

I need to download a file on the `singleChoiceAction_executed` event firing. Here's my code:

```
private void templatePickAction_Execute(object sender, SingleChoiceActionExecuteEventArgs e)
{
    Stream Stream = new MemoryStream();
    var item = View.ObjectSpace.GetObjects<xDicExcelTemplates>().Where(f => f.Name == templatePickAction.SelectedItem.Caption).FirstOrDefault();
    if (item != null)
        item.FileTemplate.SaveToStream(Stream);
        Stream.Position = 0;
        ResponseWriter.WriteFileToResponse(Stream, "1.xlsx");
}
```

But it doesn't work while it executes asynchronously.

How can I make an action execute Synchronously?

Comment: 1)  Not sure if this is just a typo, but your indents make it look like only line line is executed if your if statement is true. 2)  There's nothing that I see here that shows something explicitly executing asynchronously.  Why do you think this is running async rather than just synchronously on the UI thread as a delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG. Maybe it will be helpful for someone. Well, in ProjectName.Module.Web (or just ProjectName.Web) I needed to open Model - ActionDesign - Actions. Then I chose my action and set IsPostBackRequired property True. That's all.

Also, to get the value of this property

```
var choiceAction = (menuItem.ActionProcessor as MenuActionItemBase).Action as SingleChoiceAction;
bool usePostBack = (choiceAction as ActionBase).Model.GetValue<bool>("IsPostBackRequired");
```

That's not a genious thing, but it was hard for me to find